# Specifying priors in MCMCglmm

Tags: r

I've working on this for hours and just can't figure things out on my own. Would really appreciate any help.

For my dependent variable (`Outcome`), I collected 4 responses from each Subject over 4 trials. Each trial was coded either `POSITIVE`, `NEGATIVE`, or `AMBIVALENT`. The independent variables: `Condition`, `Gender`, and `Age.Range` all have 2 levels each.

This is a subset of my data:

```
Subject Trial   Outcome Age.Range Gender Condition
PHIL060     1      AMBI         Y      2         1
PHIL060     2  NEGATIVE         Y      2         1
PHIL060     3      AMBI         Y      2         1
PHIL060     4      AMBI         Y      2         1
PHIL056     1  POSITIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL056     2      <NA>         Y      1         2
PHIL056     3  POSITIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL056     4  POSITIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL057     1  NEGATIVE         Y      1         1
PHIL057     2  NEGATIVE         Y      1         1
PHIL057     3  NEGATIVE         Y      1         1
PHIL057     4  NEGATIVE         Y      1         1
PHIL028     1  POSITIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL028     2  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL028     3  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL028     4  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL007     1  POSITIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL007     2  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL007     3  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL007     4  NEGATIVE         Y      1         2
PHIL109     1      AMBI         Y      2         1
PHIL109     2      AMBI         Y      2         1
PHIL109     3      AMBI         O      2         1
PHIL109     4      AMBI         O      2         1
PHIL031     1  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL031     2  NEGATIVE         O      2         2 
PHIL031     3  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL031     4  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL032     1  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL032     2  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL032     3  NEGATIVE         O      2         2
PHIL032     4  POSITIVE         O      2         2
PHIL042     1  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL042     2  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL042     3  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL042     4  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL100     1  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL100     2  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL100     3  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL100     4  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL017     1  POSITIVE         1      1         1
PHIL017     2  POSITIVE         1      1         1
PHIL017     3  POSITIVE         1      1         1
PHIL017     4  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL018     1  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL018     2  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL018     3      AMBI         1      1         1
PHIL018     4  NEGATIVE         1      1         1
PHIL020     1  NEGATIVE         1      2         2
PHIL020     2  NEGATIVE         1      2         2
PHIL020     3  NEGATIVE         1      2         2
PHIL020     4  NEGATIVE         1      2         2
PHIL043     1  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL043     2  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL043     3  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL043     4  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL078     1  NEGATIVE         1      1         2
PHIL078     2  POSITIVE         1      1         2
PHIL078     3  POSITIVE         1      1         2
PHIL078     4  POSITIVE         1      1         2
```

I'm trying the `MCMCglmm` function:

```
AP.PHIL <- read.csv ("AP_PHIL.csv")
library(MCMCglmm)
k <- length(levels(my.data$Outcome))
I <- diag(k-1)
J <- matrix(rep(1, (k-1)^2), c(k-1, k-1))

m <- MCMCglmm(Outcome ~ Condition*Age.Range + Condition*Gender, 
random = ~ Subject,
rcov = ~ us(trait):units,
prior = list(
R = list(fix=1, V=0.5 * (I + J), n = 3),
G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(3), n = 3))),
      burnin = 15000,
      nitt = 40000,
      family = "categorical",
      data = my.data)
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Error in priorformat(if (NOpriorG) { : 
>       V is the wrong dimension for some prior$G/prior$R elements

Can someone please advise me on how best to edit my priors?

Comment: can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: Hi Prof. Bolker, I have edited my post to include my data. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like your grouping (`G`) prior should just be a 1x1 matrix/scalar, rather than 3x3, so

```
G = list(G1 = list(V = diag(1), n = 3)))
```

should work.

In hindsight this is clear because you have a simple (intercept-only) model for the grouping factor (so the random effect has just a single variance), but the way I figured it out was to look at the error message, guessing that I needed to `debug(MCMCglmm:::priorformat)`, then stepping through the function until I got to

```
if (any(dim(prior$V) != sum(nfl))) {
    stop("V is the wrong dimension for some prior$G/prior$R elements")
}
## Browse[2]> dim(prior$V)
## [1] 3 3
## Browse[2]> sum(nfl)
## [1] 1
```

It might be helpful if the error message were modified to be more informative, e.g.

```
if (any(dim(prior$V) != sum(nfl))) {
    stop("V is the wrong dimension for ",
         "some prior$G/prior$R elements: (G element dimension=(",
         paste(dim(prior$V),collapse=","),
         "), proper dimension=",sum(nfl),")")

}
```